# VBS scripts keep stopping

Tags: vbscript

Relative newbie here.  My VBS scripts keep terminating for no reason.  Even a simple wscript.echo command has issues.  The message box will pop up, but then immediately closes.  If I have an error in my code, it will flash the error but then even THAT will close before I can read it.

I have to force quit a script yesterday that WOULDN'T terminate and now today this is happening even after a restart.  Any thoughts.

Comment: Okay I think I found it in the registry.  The Timeout setting for the Windows Script Host apparently got set to 1 which caused it to close.  When I change it to 0, it runs as normal.  Did I just create new problems for myself though?

Comment: You didn't have to hack the registry. Try `Start` -> `Run` -> `Wscript` (or `Wscript` from command-line console). Out of curiosity, what the procedure you have used _to force quit a script yesterday_?

Comment: In task manager under processes the script showed up as wscript.exe so I just ended that process.

Comment: Provide here a code snippet, please. To do that, edit your question and paste there just a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example, according to [Help others reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)